# C# asp.net Need to validate if given textbox is in specific IP range using netmask,

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How do I warn or provide info to users if IP address entered in the textbox is not in given range but not block them from hitting submit,

Thank You

Comment: Can you please expand you question to include information on what you have tried already, and how it failed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking a UI question how to code the web page to trigger the check, or the server back end, or an algorithm question on how to do the actual comparison?